# Correspondence between SAS proc surveyreg and R svyglm

Tags: r, regression, survey, sas

I am trying to model my `proc surveyreg` from SAS in R, because their `survey` package provides an IV option that I intend to use.

```
proc surveyreg data=df varmethod=brr(fay);
class IC152Q02HA;
weight w_fstuwt;
repweights w_fsturwt1-w_fsturwt80;
model score_m = IC152Q02HA active_l passive_l  gender klasse_8 indvandrer ESCS 
public INTICT SCHSIZE MMINS C_ID/ solution;
run;
```

When modeling the following in R, I do obtain very close estimates, but my standard errors are slightly larger.

```
# Define the survey design
dstrat <- svydesign(id = ~1,
                    mse = TRUE,
                    method = "brr",
                    weight = ~W_FSTUWT,
                    repweights = rep_weights,
                    data = df,
                    fay = 0.5,
                    na.action = na.omit)
  
# Fit the survey regression model
svyreg_model <- svyglm(score_m ~ as.factor(IC152Q02HA) + active_l + passive_l + 
                         as.factor(Gender) + klasse_8 + indvandrer + ESCS + public + INTICT + 
                         SCHSIZE + MMINS + C_ID, 
                       design = dstrat)
```

I've studied the `proc surveyreg` and R survey documentation, and cannot identify what the difference is.

Can anyone identify the difference/problem/cause (maybe the software have different Hadamard matrix generation and replication processes?) or am I using the wrong approach in R `survey`?

Comment: Might be that `weight = ~W_FSTUWT` implies a regression on `W_FSTUWT`. Try `weight = W_FSTUWT` or `weight = df$W_FSTUWT` .

Comment: @LukasLohse -- that tilde is the standard specification for the weight/cluster/strata variables in the `survey` package (that the variable is nested within the supplied `data=` dataframe).

Comment: There isn't any new Hadamard matrix generation going on in either set of code; the Hadamard matrix is implied by the replicate weights.

Comment: What exactly is `rep_weights` in the R code? Could it maybe include `W_FSTUWT`?  Also, is the ratio of the R standard errors to SAS standard errors constant across all the variables or not?

Comment: @ThomasLumley `rep_weights` is just a vector of replication weights `w_fsturwt1-w_fsturwt80` e.g.  ```rep_weights <- c("W_FSTURWT1", ..."W_FSTURWT80")```

Comment: @ThomasLumley the ratio of R std. errors to SAS std. errors are not constant across all variables. most have a ratio between 1,07-1,14. Few variables have smaller std. errors, such that the ratio is around 0,95-0,97

Comment: @StineFürst -- (this may not be the root cause) in R you would ideally have the replicate weights stored not as a single vector, but as columns in your main data frame (? safest) or as a separate dataframe with the same row order (not so safe, as not tied to the dataframe and hence prone to issues from independent re-ordering of rows). By making one long vector, you are relying on R to coerce the vector to a matrix... and that might not always work as intended.

Comment: @James_Stanley they are in the data frame; `rep_weights` is a vector of column names.  `svrepdesign` won't coerce a vector of weights to a matrix, because that wouldn't be safe.

Comment: Are there missing values?  I think `SURVEYREG`s `NOMCAR` option, which isn't the default, matches what `svyglm` does

Comment: @ThomasLumley thanks, I'd missed the quote marks in the OP comment above (so a vector of column names, not a vector of weights)

Comment: @JamesStanley sorry for the confusion! It is a vector of column names just as Thomas explains.

Comment: @ThomasLumley There are missing values, and I have used the na.omit option because, from my understanding, this is listwise deletion (which is also the default in proc surveyreg). When I use the NOMCAR option (with MISSING) in SAS, my std.errors do become more similar, but they still differ :\ However I think you could be on to something in terms of missing values and the way that `surveyreg` and `svydesign` handle them.

Comment: @StineFürst -- that was my fault for trying to read and comment too early in the morning